# Display Value From Sqlite Database In An XML Format Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
    <?php

$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 600; URL=$url1;");
header("Content-type: text/xml");

try
{

$db = new PDO("sqlite:/bigdb.sql");

$result = $db->query('SELECT "value" FROM event_log AS t1 JOIN (SELECT MAX("time") AS max_time FROM event_log WHERE "eid" = 7) AS t2 ON t1."time" = t2.max_time WHERE t1."eid" = 7');

$xml_output  = '<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n';
$xml_output .= "<entries>\n";

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $xml_output .= "\t<entry>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<WarmIn>" . $row['value'] . "</WarmIn>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t</entry>\n";
}

$xml_output .= "</entries>";
$db = null;

}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

This doesn't show any values, however, if I want to display the data only as a plain text, without XML, it works, but now, leaving it as it is, the page is simply blank, no errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're not actually outputting anything in that code - is that just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Suggest you have a look at [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) This will help ensure you cretae valid XML Documents

Comment: @iainn I would like to output the data in the XML structure. Is that what I'm missing?